# Does boundedness in topological vector space imply boundedness in subspace

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological vector space, $Y$ be a subspace. If $M\subset Y$ is bounded in $X$ (i.e. for every open set $U$ of $X$, there exists $\alpha$,s.t. if $\left|\beta\right|>\left|\alpha\right|$ $M\subset \beta U$), is it true that $M$ is bounded in $Y$?

Comment: The open sets in $Y$ are just the open sets of $X$ intersected with $Y$. Since $M \subset Y$, then the answer is yes.

Comment: Is your definition of boundedness correct? I.e. take $M = [-1,1]$ and $U = (0,1)$ with $\mathbb{R}$ as a real vectorspace. I think you just have to show the property for every open neighborhood of $0$.